# Pass data between dialog form

Tags: vb.net

i want to pass data from my FrmArmy to FrmMain and i use login form to open FrmMain..

```
Me.Hide
Dim FMain As New FrmMain
FMain.ShowDialog()
```

then i open FrmArmy from FrmMain..

```
Dim FArmy As New FrmArmy
FArmy.ShowDialog()
BtnArmy.Enabled = False
```

and what i want here is.. how to change BtnArmy in FrmMain to

```
BtnArmy.Enabled = True
```

when FrmArmy Closed

This Code Does not working..

```
FrmMain.BtnArmy.Enabled = True
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood. Mind clarifying a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrmMain` is a class, you need to disable it on the instance `FMain`

```
Dim FArmy As New FrmArmy
Me.BtnArmy.Enabled = False      ' disable on show
FArmy.ShowDialog()
Me.BtnArmy.Enabled = True       ' reenable after it hides (?)
```

We have no context, I assume this is in a Button Click event.  This may not be needed, because they cant click stuff on other forms while the dialog is open, anyway.

But you have another issue: Dialogs are resources which are not automatically disposed.  If these are called a lot, you could leak resources:

```
Using fArmy As New FrmArmy
    Me.BtnArmy.Enabled = False      ' disable on show
    FArmy.ShowDialog()
    Me.BtnArmy.Enabled = True       ' reenable after it hides (?)
End Using           ' auto dispose of Dialog
```

Comment: yes this is what iam talking about.. and yes iam using button_click event to open FrmArmy, this is so simple but working. Thanks. if i may ask another question how to change label1.text = "FrmArmy Closed"  in FrmMain when FrmArmy Closed.. thanks again.

Comment: same thing, just add the code after `.ShowDialog` before your code exits the event procedure